# How to build ionic app based on laravel project

Tags: php, angular, laravel, ionic-framework

I have a laravel project and ionic app

I'm trying to login and display my home view(laravel) in ionic app Here is what i have done:

rout api.php :

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
    Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
    Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    Route::group([
      'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
        Route::get('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
        Route::get('user', [AuthController::class, 'user']);
    });
});
```

auth controller :

```
public function login(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'remember' => 'boolean'
        ]);
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);
        $user = $request->user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token; 
        if ($request->remember)
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
        $token->save();
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                $tokenResult->token->expires_at
            )->toDateTimeString()
        ]);
    }
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'user_type' => 'required|boolean'
        ]);
        // dd($request);
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->user_type= $request->user_type;
        $user->save();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
        ], 201);
    }
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->token()->revoke();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully logged out'
        ]);
    }
  
    /**
     * Get the authenticated User
     *
     * @return [json] user object
     */
    public function user(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json($request->user());
    }
```

and home contrller is:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        return response()->view('home');
    }
```

thats for laravel project

for ionic authservice.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  isLoggedIn = false;
  token:any;
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private storage: NativeStorage,
    private env: EnvService,
  ) { }
  login(email: String, password: String) {
    return this.http.post(this.env.API_URL + 'auth/login',
      {email: email, password: password}
    ).pipe(
      tap(token => {
        this.storage.setItem('token', token)
        .then(
          () => {
            console.log('Token Stored');
          },
          error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
        );
        this.token = token;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        console.log(token);
        return token;
      }),
    );
  }
  register(name: String, email: String, password: String, user_type: Boolean) {
    return this.http.post(this.env.API_URL + 'auth/register',
      {name: name, email: email, password: password,  user_type: user_type}
    )
  }
  logout() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': "Bearer "+this.token
    });
    return this.http.get(this.env.API_URL + 'auth/logout', { headers: headers })
    .pipe(
      tap(data => {
        this.storage.remove("token");
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        delete this.token;
        return data;
      })
    )
  }
  user() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': "Bearer "+this.token
    });
    return this.http.get<User>(this.env.API_URL + 'auth/user', { headers: headers })
    .pipe(data => {
      this.storage.remove("token");
      this.isLoggedIn = false;
      delete this.token;
      return data;
    })
  }
  getToken() {
    return this.storage.getItem('token').then(
      data => {
        this.token = data;
        if(this.token != null) {
          this.isLoggedIn=true;
        } else {
          this.isLoggedIn=false;
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.token = null;
        this.isLoggedIn=false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

login.ts

```
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(
    private modalController: ModalController,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private alertService: AlertService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  // Dismiss Login Modal
  dismissLogin() {
    this.modalController.dismiss();
  }

  // On Register button tap, dismiss login modal and open register modal
  async registerModal() {
    this.dismissLogin();
    const registerModal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: RegisterPage
    });
    return await registerModal.present();
  }

  login(form: NgForm) {
    this.authService.login(form.value.email, form.value.password).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.alertService.presentToast("Logged In");
      },
      error => {
      },
      () => {
        this.dismissLogin();
        this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/dashboard');
      }
    );
  }
}
```

for now i can log in successfully what i need next to display Home page after logging in How can i do that?

Comment: Are you trying to display the Laravel Homepage from Ionic? Those are two different things. If you want a homepage you need to create it in ionic and then navigate to that view from Ionic when you receive the token

Comment: I recommend you to take a look to this project that I made: https://github.com/Jatapiaro/iot-containers-backend and it’s front end https://github.com/Jatapiaro/iot-containers-app which is made in ReactNative but it will be almost the exact same haberlo g

Comment: Yes thats what I'm trying to do, I did see your project I have not understand that much. if you can share any tutorial it will be helpful thank you

Comment: This is what I don't know how to do it "navigate to that view from Ionic when you receive the token"

Comment: In that case I recommend you this other project that I have, it was made in Laravel and Ionic. https://bitbucket.org/fonditas/ionic-fonditas-app/src/master/ and https://bitbucket.org/fonditas/fonditas-back-end/src/master/. That larval project uses JWT, for the tokens, but I recommend to use laravel passport for it or anything in the new Laravel 8 documentation. To answer your question quickly take a look at this snippet of the fonditas app project. https://gist.github.com/Jatapiaro/360e6f1f6913b855fd3eec6fa24f931f In the register method.

Comment: After a successful registration I use navController to navigate to a specific page.

Comment: oh thank you so much !! I will try it now. all make sense thank you

Comment: can I ask  again :)

Comment: Of course, you can ask again.